# mi programa se detiene antes en C

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo un programa en C. Tengo el siguiente inconveniente:

Estoy haciendo un programa en C, recien comienzo a estudiar. hace poco empecé la Uni y tengo que estudiar C.

Mi programa se detiene antes de tiempo y no me deja continuarlo. Por qué sucede esto?.. Intenté limpiar el buffer de teclado antes del scanf pero nada....

Alguna idea? Gracias... Acá abajo les dejo mi código, no encuentro el error...  (se podria haber usado for por lo que me dijeron pero todavía no lo aprendí bien. tiene algo que ver eso con mi error en la ejecución?)

acá va mi código, gracias :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_STR 128
#define INFO 3    
#define USERS 5   

typedef struct {    
    char campeon[MAX_STR];
    int AMA[INFO];          // AMA[INFO] (AMA= asesinatos, muertes, asistencias)
} juego;

typedef struct {
    char nombre[MAX_STR];
    juego partida;
    int usuario;
} invocador;

int main(){
    invocador usuario[USERS]; 
    int AMA_total[INFO],campeon;
    double ratio;
    
    printf("\n\n\tDATOS JUGADOR 1: ");
    printf("\n\n\tCual es tu nombre de invocador?: ");
    scanf("%s", usuario[0].nombre);

    printf("\n\n\tCon que campeon jugaste la ultima partida?: ");
    scanf("%s", &usuario[0].partida.campeon);
    fflush(stdin);
    
    printf("\n\n\tCuantos asesinatos has hecho?: ");
    scanf("%d", &usuario[0].partida.AMA[0]); // 
    
    printf("\n\n\tCuantas veces moriste?: ");
    scanf("%d", &usuario[0].partida.AMA[1]); //scanf("%d", &usuario.j1.partida.AMA[1]);
    
    printf("\n\n\tCuantas asistencias hiciste?: ");
    scanf("%d", &usuario[0].partida.AMA[2]);
    
    ratio = (double) (usuario[0].partida.AMA[0] + usuario[0].partida.AMA[2]) / usuario[0].partida.AMA[1];
    
    printf("%s jugador 1, tu AMA ratio con %s ha sido: %2.lf.\n", usuario[0].nombre,ratio,usuario[0].partida.campeon);
    
    
    printf("\n\n\tDATOS JUGADOR 2: ");
    printf("\n\n\tCual es tu nombre de invocador?: ");
    scanf("%s", usuario[1].nombre);

    printf("\n\n\tCon que campeon jugaste la ultima partida?: ");
    scanf("%s", &usuario[1].partida.campeon);
    fflush(stdin);
    
    printf("\n\n\tCuantos asesinatos has hecho?: ");
    scanf("%d", &usuario[1].partida.AMA[0]); 
    
    printf("\n\n\tCuantas veces moriste?: ");
    scanf("%d", &usuario[1].partida.AMA[1]); //scanf("%d", &usuario.j1.partida.AMA[1]); //
    
    printf("\n\n\tCuantas asistencias hiciste?: ");
    scanf("%d", &usuario[1].partida.AMA[2]);
    
    ratio = (double) (usuario[1].partida.AMA[0] + usuario[1].partida.AMA[2]) / usuario[1].partida.AMA[1];
    
    printf("%s jugador 2, tu AMA ratio con %s ha sido: %2.lf.\n", usuario[1].nombre, ratio, usuario[1].partida.campeon);
    
    
    printf("\n\n\tDATOS JUGADOR 3: ");
    printf("\n\n\tCual es tu nombre de invocador?: ");
    scanf("%s", usuario[2].nombre);

    printf("\n\n\tCon que campeon jugaste la ultima partida?: ");
    scanf("%s", &usuario[2].partida.campeon);
    fflush(stdin);
    
    printf("\n\n\tCuantos asesinatos has hecho?: ");
    scanf("%d", &usuario[2].partida.AMA[0]); 
    
    printf("\n\n\tCuantas veces moriste?: ");
    scanf("%d", &usuario[2].partida.AMA[1]); //scanf("%d", &usuario.j1.partida.AMA[1]); // 
    
    printf("\n\n\tCuantas asistencias hiciste?: ");
    scanf("%d", &usuario[2].partida.AMA[2]);
    
    ratio = (double) (usuario[2].partida.AMA[0] + usuario[2].partida.AMA[2]) / usuario[2].partida.AMA[1];
    
    printf("%s jugador 3, tu AMA ratio con %s ha sido: %2.lf.\n", usuario[2].nombre, ratio, usuario[2].partida.campeon);
    
    
    printf("\n\n\tDATOS JUGADOR 4: ");
    printf("\n\n\tCual es tu nombre de invocador?: ");
    scanf("%s", usuario[3].nombre);

    printf("\n\n\tCon que campeon jugaste la ultima partida?: ");
    scanf("%s", &usuario[3].partida.campeon);
    fflush(stdin);
    
    printf("\n\n\tCuantos asesinatos has hecho?: ");
    scanf("%d", &usuario[3].partida.AMA); 
    
    printf("\n\n\tCuantas veces moriste?: ");
    scanf("%d", &usuario[3].partida.AMA); 
    
    printf("\n\n\tCuantas asistencias hiciste?: ");
    scanf("%d", &usuario[3].partida.AMA);
    
    ratio = (double) (usuario[3].partida.AMA[0] + usuario[3].partida.AMA[2]) / usuario[3].partida.AMA[1];
    
    printf("%s jugador 4, tu AMA ratio con %s ha sido: %2.lf.\n", usuario[3].nombre, ratio, usuario[3].partida.campeon);
    
    
    printf("\n\n\tDATOS JUGADOR 5: ");
    printf("\n\n\tCual es tu nombre de invocador?: ");
    scanf("%s", usuario[4].nombre);

    printf("\n\n\tCon que campeon jugaste la ultima partida?: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", &usuario[4].partida.campeon);
    
    printf("\n\n\tCuantos asesinatos has hecho?: ");
    scanf("%d", &usuario[4].partida.AMA); 
    
    printf("\n\n\tCuantas veces moriste?: ");
    scanf("%d", &usuario[4].partida.AMA); //scanf("%d", &usuario.j1.partida.AMA[1]); 
    
    printf("\n\n\tCuantas asistencias hiciste?: ");
    scanf("%d", &usuario[4].partida.AMA);
    
    ratio= (double) (usuario[4].partida.AMA[0] + usuario[4].partida.AMA[2]) / usuario[4].partida.AMA[1];
    
    printf("%s jugador 5, tu AMA ratio con %s ha sido: %2.lf.\n", usuario[4].nombre, ratio, usuario[4].partida.campeon);

    AMA_total[0] = usuario[0].partida.AMA[0] + usuario[1].partida.AMA[0] + usuario[2].partida.AMA[0] + usuario[3].partida.AMA[0] + usuario[4].partida.AMA[0]; //asesinatos de la partida
    AMA_total[1] = usuario[0].partida.AMA[1] + usuario[1].partida.AMA[1] + usuario[2].partida.AMA[1] + usuario[3].partida.AMA[1] + usuario[4].partida.AMA[1]; // muertes
    AMA_total[2] = usuario[0].partida.AMA[2] + usuario[1].partida.AMA[2] + usuario[2].partida.AMA[2] + usuario[3].partida.AMA[2] + usuario[4].partida.AMA[2]; // asistencias
    
    ratio = (double) (AMA_total[0] + AMA_total[2]) / AMA_total[1]; // KDA ratio de del KDA total de la partida. Fórmula: (K+A)/D
        
    printf("Usuarios %s, %s, %s, %s y %s, el AMA de tu partida fue %d/%d/d y tu ratio fue %.2lf.\n", usuario[0].nombre,usuario[1].nombre,usuario[2].nombre,usuario[3].nombre,usuario[4].nombre,campeon, ratio);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pues sin ver el codigo no podemos hacer absolutamente nada. Usa [este
link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/465432/edit) para editar tu pregunta y
añadir el codigo.

Comment: listo ya lo agregué

Comment: Cuando estas leyendo los strings, en todos los casos que vi
tienes un `&` de mas. Ademas, porque tienes tanto codigo
repetido, no es mas facil colocarlo dentro de un loop?

Comment: porque en este ejercicio me solicitan hacerlo sin bucles y supongo que es para entender bien el funcionamiento de las struct. no entendi bien lo que dijiste que tengo ampersands de más, podrias decirme cuales? gracias

Comment: Tu programa se detiene en una linea  específica  o  aveces  se detiene  en  una  y otras veces en otra? El código que has puesto en tu  pregunta es la ultima versión o ya  has realizado modificaciones.  Supongo que el  primer scanf siempre  lo hace bien.

Comment: Esta  linea: `scanf("%d", &usuario[3].partida.AMA);`  la  tienes en varios lados. ¿Es correcta? AMA es una arreglo y que crees que pueda estar haciendo el scanf?  ` int AMA[INFO]; ` asi tienes definido AMA

Comment: Y como dice @Pablochaches tienes unos `&` demás.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich se detiene en la ultima linea de jugador 1. es decir queda el ejecutable detenido, no ingresa nunca DATOS DEL JUGADOR 2.

Comment: no entiendo tu mensaje sobre mi arreglo y el scanf, Juan.. no entiendo muy bien la verdad. es frustrante

Comment: me falta un vector en esa linea de scanf? usuario[3].partida.AMA[0] y asi sigue hasta el vector 3?

Comment: Esta linea la ejecuta: `printf("%s jugador 1, tu AMA ratio con %s ha sido: %2.lf.\n", usuario[0].nombre,ratio,usuario[0].partida.campeon);`? Bueno  esta linea  deberia ser así:  `printf("%s jugador 1, tu AMA ratio con %s ha sido: %2.lf.\n", usuario[0].nombre,usuario[0].partida.campeon,ratio);`.

Comment: Esta linea: ` scanf("%s", &usuario[0].partida.campeon);` deberia ser ` scanf("%s", usuario[0].partida.campeon);`. Esos son los `&` demas.  Arregla esas dos lineas y ya deberías llegar a DATOS DE JUGADOR 2. (la linea del printf y del scanf)

Comment: SOS UN GROSO JUAN!!!!!!!!

Comment: quitale el `&` a `scanf("%s", &usuario[2].partida.campeon);` para que quede `scanf("%s", usuario[2].partida.campeon); y en el printf del jugador 2 debe  quedar `printf("%s jugador 2, tu AMA ratio con %s ha sido: %2.lf.\n", usuario[1].nombre,  usuario[1].partida.campeon, ratio);`. GROSO es que estamos bien? jeje

Comment: groso significa que sos un genio y muchas gracias por ayudar. eres crack Juan, solucionado!

Comment: Las 3 lineas : `scanf("%d", &usuario[3].partida.AMA);` deberian  ser scanf("%d", &usuario[3].partida.AMA[0]); scanf("%d", &usuario[3].partida.AMA[1]); scanf("%d", &usuario[3].partida.AMA[2]);  Corrige  tambien  la usuario[4].

Comment: Te lo pongo como respuesta ok?

Comment: Espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 1):

Tu código  tiene algunos problemas  en los scanf y printf. Te  los menciono:

1. La linea   `scanf("%s", &usuario[0].partida.campeon);` al poner el  `&` delante de usuario estas haciendo referencia a una direccion de memoria, por lo que, el resultado puede ser desastrozo. Como `campeon` es un arreglo solo basta colocarlo sin  el `&`: `scanf("%s", usuario[0].partida.campeon);`
2. La  linea     `printf("%s jugador 1, tu AMA ratio con %s ha sido: %2.lf.\n", usuario[0].nombre,ratio,usuario[0].partida.campeon);` si observas el formato  tiene una secuencia `%s`, `%s` y `%2.lf`, sin embargo, no guarda el mismo orden cuando pones las variables: `nombre,ratio,campeon`que sería `%s,%2.lf,%s`. Por lo tanto, es un error. Corrigelo de la siguiente forma: `printf("%s jugador 1, tu AMA ratio con %s ha sido: %2.lf.\n", usuario[0].nombre,usuario[0].partida.campeon, ratio);` para que esté alineado al formato.
3. Las  dos observaciones anteriores las tienes que corregir  tambien para usuario[3]  y usuario[4].
4. Por último, tienes `scanf("%d", &usuario[3].partida.AMA);` pero AMA es un arreglo, por lo tanto, aqui tambien vas a tener problemas de memoria. El `C` te permite  todo sin avisar, se debe tener bastante  cuidado con  eso. Cambia las lineas por `scanf("%d", &usuario[3].partida.AMA[0]);`, `scanf("%d", &usuario[3].partida.AMA[1]);`, `scanf("%d", &usuario[3].partida.AMA[2]);`. Igual haces para  usuario[4].